# NoMethodError in SessionsController#create when calling a method in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

I am working on rails 3 app and using the koala gem to get a connection to the facebook graph api.I am also using omniauth to autenticate users.

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `add_friends' for #<User:0x007fcfcb1a87e8>

app/models/user.rb:28:in `block in from_omniauth'
app/models/user.rb:6:in `tap'
app/models/user.rb:6:in `from_omniauth'
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

In ruby docs it says: "Raised when a method is called on a receiver which doesn't have it defined and also fails to respond with method_missing."

***But I have a metod defined, so why do I get this error? And how can I fix it?***

In my SessionController I do something like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
  end
end
```

This is my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :token, :email, :name, :first_name, :last_name, :image, :gender, :location, :school, :year
  has_many :friends

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
      user.first_name = auth["info"]["first_name"]
      user.last_name = auth["info"]["last_name"]
      user.image = auth["info"]["image"]
      user.email = auth["info"]["email"]
      user.gender = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["gender"]
      user.location = auth["extra"]["raw_info"]["location"]["name"]          
      user.token = auth["credentials"]["token"]

      user.add_friends
      user.save!
      user

    end

    def add_friends
      @facebook.get_connections("me", "friends").each do |hash|
        self.friends.find(:name => hash['name'], :uid => hash['id']).first_or_create
      end
    end

    private 

    def facebook
      @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted `def add_friends` is actually inside your `from_omniauth` class method and so ends up being a class method too, rather than an instance method.

Move that (and the facebook method) out of there and you should be ok. You probably also want to be calling your `facebook` method rather than accessing the instance variable directly.

Comment: can you please show me, I moved the method like this: https://gist.github.com/3025599 and now I get a for get_connections insted: undefined method `get_connections' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You're using `@facebook` without setting it. Do `facebook.get_connections(...)` instead

Comment: Then I get: undefined local variable or method `facebook' for #<User:0x007ff4a1760ff0>

Comment: you also need to move the Facebook method out of that class method